# $\ell^p(I)$ space and a dense set of this space

Tags: functional-analysis, cardinals, lp-spaces

> Let $I$ be an infinite set and $1\leq p<\infty$. Show that $\ell^p(I)$ has a dense set of the same cardinality as $I$.

For this I put

$$X=\{(x_i); x_i\in \Bbb C , x_i=0 \text{ for all but for finitely many } i\in I\}.$$

For every $(\alpha_i) \in \ell^p(I)$ we have $\sum_{i\in I}|\alpha_i |^p < \infty$ . So, for every $\epsilon >0$ , $\sum_{i\in I-\{i_1,...,i_n\}}|\alpha_i |^p < \epsilon$ then $x=(x_i)$ where $x_{i_j}=\alpha_{i_j}$ for $j=1,...,n$ belongs to $X$ and $\|\alpha - x\| < \epsilon$, thus $X $ is dense in  $\ell^p(I)$ . Am I right? How can I show that the cardinality $X$ is the same $I$?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to define $X$ such that $x_i \in D$ for some countable dense subset $D\subset \mathbb C$, or $|X| \geq |\mathbb R|$. More of less the same argument will show that  $X$ is dense in $\ell^p(I)$.

To show that $X$ has the same cardinality as $I$, define $F : I \to X$ to be the map sending $i_0\in I$ to $(x_i)\in X$ which has the only nonzero entry 1 when $i=i_0$ (Let's say $1\in D$). This map is injective and thus $|I|\leq |X|$. On the other hand, let $X_n$ be the set of all sequence $(x_i)\in X$ with $n$ nonzero terms and define

$$X_n \to (I\times D)^n,\ \ (x_i)\mapsto \big( (i_1, x_{i_1}), \cdots, (i_n, x_{i_n})\big).$$

Then this map is injective and $|X_n|\leq |(I\times D)^n|= |I \times D| = |I|$ as $I$ is infinite ($|I|\geq |D|$). Thus $|X|\leq |I|$. Summing up we have $|I|=|X|$.

Comment: dear John@ is the set that I defined dense in $\ell^p(I)?$

Comment: I can not show that X is dense in $\ell^p(I)$. before I use this fact that finitly menay number is summable but it's not correct for countably many.

Comment: @NIKA: Your argument there is correct.

Comment: John: So I can choose my dense subspace and like you show that their cardinality are the same. Is it correct?

Comment: @nika: Like I said, if for example $I = \mathbb Z$, then your $X$ would have cardinality larger than $|I|$. You need to choose a countably dense subspace $D$.